# Testing with Ionic-karma-jasmine

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am new to angular and ionic, I need to know how to unit test, specifically, are there any test files that I write my test code in?

I am currently working on ionic 3.

I have installed karma and jasmine using npm, my devDependencies look like this

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "karma": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.4"
  },
```

Say I have a function like this in a component.ts file:

```
add (a:number,b:number) {
    return a+b
  }
```

Where do I write the test function for it?
also how do I run the test function? 
how do I see the results?

Answer (score 1):

Usually unit tests for angular/ typescript will be written in separate files which are typically named as .spec.ts (which can be stored in the same directory as the component file or in a tests folder).

in the package.json under scripts section we declare the npm alias to trigger the ng tests.

```
"scripts": {
            .....
            "test": "ng test"
            ...
                }
```

which can be triggered in console running in package.json directory

```
npm run test
```

karma picks up default settings in karma.conf.js and looks for files which are named in format **.spec.ts. (which can be configured)

The success / failure messages will be displayed in the console.
you can also use other node modules like **istanbul** and generate nice colorful stats which can be view-able along with coverage report.